# Run OpenThread Border Router in Docker container on custom network

Tags: docker

I'm trying to setup an OpenThread Border Router (OTBR) on my Raspberry Pi. When running OTBR in a docker container as suggested in the [official guide](https://openthread.io/guides/border-router/docker/run?hl=en) apps like Google Home or other cannot connect to it.

When starting the docker container with:

```
docker run --sysctl "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1 net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1" -p 8080:80 --dns=127.0.0.1 -it --volume /dev/ttyACM0:/dev/ttyACM0 --privileged openthread/otbr --radio-url spinel+hdlc+uart:///dev/ttyACM0
```

no apps can connect to the border router. However if I execute these command beforehand on the host:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1 
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

and then start the container like this

```
docker run --net=host --dns=127.0.0.1 -it --volume /dev/ttyACM0:/dev/ttyACM0 --privileged openthread/otbr --radio-url spinel+hdlc+uart:///dev/ttyACM0
```

everything works as expected and apps can connect to the border router. Because I already have a container using port 80 on my host machine I would like to use a custom docker network. I'm not quite sure how to do that as the Thread communication requires at least IPv6 and also UDP packets for the DNS discovery. Do you have any ideas for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using macvlan network to attach it to your house lan. Something like:

```yaml
services:
  openthread-border-router:
    image: openthread/otbr
    command: --radio-url spinel+hdlc+uart:///dev/ttyUSB0?uart-baudrate=460800
    devices:
      - /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Nabu_Casa_SkyConnect_v1.0_48a8c509fbe1ed11a357ec5162c613ac-if00-port0:/dev/ttyUSB0
    restart: unless-stopped
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    privileged: true
    dns:
      - "127.0.0.1"
    networks:
      name-of-network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.71

networks:
  name-of-network:
    name: name-of-network
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: interface-name-like-en0-or-something
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "192.168.1.0/24"
          gateway: "192.168.1.1"
          ip_range: "192.168.1.64/27"
```